# Cygwin command not found bad characters found in .bashrc 357\273\277

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm new to Cygwin, I just installed it and attempted to set some simple environment variables.  However, when I open the command shell, I get the error "#357\273\277 command not found"

I found an article that discusses what the problem is and how to "discover" the hidden bad character:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100612055709/http://mblog.lib.umich.edu/DataDiscussions/archives/2010/01/index.html

```
e.g. $ od -c c:\\Users\\me\\.bashrc
```

but I don't know how to resolve the issue by removing the character (which I validated was a problem in my .bashrc file using the od command).  I attempted to change the preferences view in Notepad++ to UTF-8 and ANSI to no avail, but the file was not altered at all.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before feeding your files to cygwin bash, you can do a dos2unix conversion first to take care possible conflicts like CR LF.  Open bash

name@host ~
$ dos2unix your_file.sh

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, a common problem with files saved in Notepad++ as UTF-8 and Cygwin is that Notepad++ saves UTF-8 encoded files with a *byte order mark* by default. This [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) character is not quite compatible with unix-like environments like Cygwin.

If you need unicode characters in these files, then you can try using the "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding in Notepad++, otherwise you can use ANSI or other encodings that don't use a BOM by default.

Besides the encoding, make sure the file's saved with unix (LF) line-breaks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like if I change the **encoding** from UTF-8 to ANSI (not the view preferences), the file will update and the special characters are gone, fixing the "\357\273\277 command not found" issue.  Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

One way to strip these in Linux is by using vi. If you run `vi <filename>` and then in vi use the ed command `:se fileencoding=ASCII` (or `:set fileencoding=ASCII`), this will strip the oddball characters out.

You can confirm this by saving the file and then running `od -c` on the file.

Before:

```
$ od -c changes.sql | head
0000000 357 273 277   I   N   S   E   R   T       I   N   T   O       `
```

After:

```
$ od -c changes.sql | head
0000000   I   N   S   E   R   T       I   N   T   O       `   c   o   n
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have edited your .bashrc outside of Cygwin and used a Windows editor, the editor might have messed up your newline character (ie. CR, R, etc.) You can tell Notepad++ to show hidden characters. I think you can find it in its settings. Changing charsets is one thing, but being able to see hidden characters is another.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) article mentions a few programs that you can use to convert text files from one standard to another. Try using dos2unix on the file (in the cygwin command line).