# Using /bin/sh with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sh, bin

i have to use rsync with cygwin on a Windows 7 platform.
Installed cygwin in C:\cygwin64.

```
set $PATH
```

within cmd gives (the relevant parts)

```
C:\cygwin64
C:\cygwin64\bin
C:\cygwin64\sbin
C:\cygwin64\usr\bin
C:\cygwin64\usr\sbin
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\sbin.
```

Here's my sync .sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
quelle="/cygdrive/d/synctest/"
ziel="/cygdrive/x"
heute=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
rsync -avR --delete --no-perms --no-owner --no-group "$quelle" "$ziel/$heute/" --link-dest="$ziel/last"
ln -nsf "$ziel/$heute" "$ziel/last"
```

Executing it gives

```
$ /autosync.sh
/autosync.sh: Zeile 1: #!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

I've already read through the whole internet and just found that i have to set my PATH variable right. But i did it already, didnt't i?

Thanks

Edit: Corrected a copy paste mistake regarding the quotes

Comment: The error message suggests that the shebang line is being interpreted as a command, which is a different error.  Does your file has a Unicode BOM character before the start of the script?  How exactly are you running it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cygwin command not found bad characters found in .bashrc 357\273\277](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676053/cygwin-command-not-found-bad-characters-found-in-bashrc-357-273-277)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the BOM character did the trick. I changed the encoding to UTF8 without BOM and it worked.