# IP as Linux array element throws UnknownHostException but as constant works

Tags: java, linux, bash, sockets, jsch

I have the following script in the directory `/home/test/javacall` that parses csv of IP pair , invokes a sh file that calls an executable jar to get output from these IPs.

In the below code `ip1=${IPArray[0]}` throws `UnknownHostException` from java.
But If I use the ip directly `ip1="10.10.10.10"` java code works fine. I did `System.out.println` from java and I got the same IP displayed in both cases. But in the case of `ip1=${IPArray[0]}` only, I get the exception.

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="IPPairs.csv"
array=()

while IFS="," read var1 var2 ; do
    echo $var1 $var2
    pairString="$var1***$var2"
    array+=("$pairString")
done < $INPUT

for i in "${array[@]}" ; do
    echo $i
    IPString=$(echo $i | tr '***' ' ')
    read -ra IPArray <<< "$IPString"
    ip1=${IPArray[0]}
    #ip1="10.10.10.10"
    ip2=${IPArray[1]}

    source /home/test/javacall/javacmd.sh "$ip1" "/home/test/javacall/out.txt" "show running-config all-properties"
done
```

**Exception:**

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: 10.10.10.10
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

Comment: How are you executing the bash script?

Comment: Your shell script is broken. How on earth shall we know without a crystal ball? Could you please share some text of your shell script?

Comment: Updated question with shell script.

Comment: there are differences in the command `userid pw out.txt`  `userID "pwd"`

Comment: #!/bin/bash      
java -jar /home/myname/Executor.jar 10.10.10.10 userID "pwd" outs1.txt "show running-config all-properties" works. But with $s1 fails.

Comment: What if you execute your **exact** command from the shell script? `java -jar /home/myname/Executor.jar 10.10.10.10 userid pw out.txt "show running-config all-properties"`

Comment: When I put the exact command as the only line in bash file, it works.

Comment: Use `bash -x` to enable trace-level logging. That way if you have, say, DOS newlines in the input file you're `read`ing, they'll show up as `$'...\r'` formatting in your strings in the trace. (BTW, checking for that is literally the *very first entry* in the "Before asking about problematic code" section at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: BTW, it'd also be generally good form to run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the bugs it finds. Even something as simple as `echo $i` can trigger bugs -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and/or the shellcheck warning page [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: BTW, `tr '***' ' '` is **exactly** the same as `tr '*' ' '`; `tr` operates only on character sets; it doesn't know or care how many times an instance is shown.

Comment: @itsraja Please update your question with the information you commented on Charles' answer. You should also remove the java tags from your question, as the issue is clearly with the parsing of your csv in Bash.

Comment: May be, but keeping the java tag will help those getting this exception in Linux environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println()` only shows **visible** characters.

If your input file contains DOS newlines, `System.out.println()` won't show them, but they'll still be present in your command line, and parsed as part of the IP address to connect to, causing an UnknownHostException. Converting it to a UNIX text file, as with `dos2unix`, or using `:set fileformat=unix` in vim, is typically the quickest way to fix this.

BTW, if you don't need ordering retained, an associative array is typically a more appropriate data structure to use to store pairs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A pairs=( )

while IFS=$',\r' read -r var1 var2 _ ; do
    pairs[$var1]=$var2
done <"$input"

for ip1 in "${!pairs[@]}"; do
  ip2=${pairs[$ip1]}
  # Using printf %q causes nonprintable characters to be visibly shown
  printf 'Processing pair: %q and %q\n' "$ip1" "$ip2" >&2
done
```

In the above, using `IFS=$',\r'` prevents LF characters (from the "CRLF" sequence that makes up a DOS newline) from becoming either part of `var1` or `var2`. (Adding an `_` placeholder variable to consume any additional content in a given line of the file adds extra insurance towards this point).

Comment: When I used the command printf 'Processing pair: %q and %q\n' "$ip1" "$ip2" >&2
 in my existing code I got Processing pair: $'\357\273\27710.10.10.10' and 10.10.10.11

Comment: Your answer provided the direction and creating the csv file in linux itself solved the problem.

Comment: Another way to fix that would be `ip1=${ip1#$'\357\273\277'}`

Answer (score 2):

That string (357\273\277) indicates that your csv file is encoded with a [Byte-Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the front of the file. The `read` command is not interpreting the BOM as having special meaning, just passing on the raw characters, so you see them as part of your output.

Since you didn't indicate how your source file is generated, you may be able to adjust the settings on that end to prevent writing the BOM, which is optional in many cases. Alternatively, you can work around it various ways on the script side. These questions both offer some examples:

[How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)
[Cygwin command not found bad characters found in .bashrc 357\273\277](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676053/cygwin-command-not-found-bad-characters-found-in-bashrc-357-273-277)

But honestly, if you just follow Charles Duffy's advice and run your file through dos2unix before parsing it, it should clean this up for you automatically. i.e.:

```sh
...
array=()

dos2unix $INPUT

while IFS="," read var1 var2 ; do
...
```

Or, building on Charles' version:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0+ needed" >&2; exit 1;; esac

INPUT="IPPairs.csv"
declare -A pairs=( )

dos2unix $INPUT

while IFS=$',\r' read -r var1 var2 _ ; do
    pairs[$var1]=$var2
done <"$INPUT"

for ip1 in "${!pairs[@]}"; do
  ip2=${pairs[$ip1]}
  # Using printf %q causes nonprintable characters to be visibly shown
  printf 'Processing pair: %q and %q\n' "$ip1" "$ip2" >&2
done
```

Do note that running dos2unix in your script is not necessarily the best approach, as the file only needs to be converted once. Generally speaking, it shouldn't hurt anything, especially with such a small file. Nonetheless, a better approach would be to run dos2unix as part of whatever process pushes your csv to the server, and keep it out of this script.